# Deleting dynammically created table row android

Tags: android, cursor

I am trying to delete table row created dinammically, but i can't get the right table row id, all my table rows have the same id, more that i create them, my counter sets higher id and all rows get it... I'll appreciate any help, i'm stuck on this for a few days. My method is big, but only beginning is important i think.

```
 public void getRow(String klik, int brojkica)
{
    //db=openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db = INF.getReadableDatabase();
    int count = 0;
    Cursor cursor3 = db.rawQuery("select id,Artikl, CIJENA from Artikli where");
    System.out.println(counterko);
    counterko++;
    tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setClickable(true);
    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    tr.setId(500 + counterko);

    cursor3.moveToFirst();
    final TextView sifracolumn = new TextView(this);
    sifracolumn.setId(1000 + counterko);

    sifracolumn.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    sifracolumn.setText(String.valueOf(cursor3.getInt(0)));
    sifracolumn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    sifracolumn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tr.addView(sifracolumn);
    allIDs.add(sifracolumn);//////////////////////////////////////

    final TextView artiklcolumn = new TextView(this);
    artiklcolumn.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    artiklcolumn.setId(2000 + counterko);
    artiklcolumn.setClickable(true);
    artiklcolumn.setWidth(400);
    artiklcolumn.setText(cursor3.getString(1));
    artiklcolumn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    artiklcolumn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tr.addView(artiklcolumn);
    artiklcolumn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //alert(tr.getId());
            alert(artiklcolumn.getId());
        }
    });
    final TextView cijenacolumn = new TextView(this);
    cijenacolumn.setId(3000 + count);
    cijenacolumn.setText(cursor3.getString(2));
    cijenacolumn.setWidth(120);
    cijenacolumn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    cijenacolumn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    tr.addView(cijenacolumn);

    final EditText kolicinacolumn = new EditText(this);
    kolicinacolumn.setId(4000 + counterko);
    kolicinacolumn.setText("1");
    kolicinacolumn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    kolicinacolumn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    allEds.add(kolicinacolumn);
    tr.addView(kolicinacolumn);

    final TextView iznoscolumn = new TextView(this);
    iznoscolumn.setId(5000 + counterko);
    iznoscolumn.setWidth(120);
    iznoscolumn.setText("");
    iznoscolumn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    iznoscolumn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    tr.addView(iznoscolumn);
    allTexts.add(iznoscolumn);

    if (kolicinacolumn.getText().toString() == "1")
    {

        System.out.println("kme");
        iznoscolumn.setText(cijenacolumn.getText().toString());
    }
    zaplatiti();
    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    count++;
    kolicinacolumn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {


        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            String kol = kolicinacolumn.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(kol))
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.print("Stop it");
                } catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("This is not a number");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else
            {
                Float racunam = Float.valueOf(kol);
                Float racunam2 = Float.valueOf(cijenacolumn.getText().toString());
                Float reza = racunam * racunam2;
                iznoscolumn.setText(String.valueOf(reza));
            }
            zaplatiti();
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            //TODO 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sta je ovde pitanje? Also, CTRL+SHIFT+F.

Comment: pitanje je kako izbrisati redak tablice napravljene dinamički... pokušavam je preko id-ja, al ne mogu dobiti id pravi. btw, pozdrav susjedu! :)

Comment: If you generate your table dynamically, how come you don't have IDs for generated data, even if you just count them? What is 'counterko' and where does it come from? I suspect it's a static member and that all columns share the same thing. If not, you will have to come up with a different way to 'memorize' the things you generate.

Comment: counterko is a counter, when i choose item from list, it increments mi counterko variable for 1 and add row to my table, but for some reason, my ids are always the highest number of counterko...i make five rows, my id for all table rows will be 5, but my columns are acting normaly.

Comment: I will format this code but you have to edit it and only post the relevant part where you assign your row ID's and add them to the table, OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i solved my problem..first problem was

```
tr = new TableRow(this);
```

i couldn't assign id to my table row because id didn't instantiate it in my method, so first thing to do was

```
final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
```

then i put onclicklistener on column which i wanted to be responsive and put this in..

```
 artiklcolumn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {
TableRow km= (TableRow)findViewById(tr.getId());                
alert(km);

}
```

in which i get my object, send it to alert dialog and from there to method do delete it.

```
 public void delete(TableRow tr2){

 tl.removeView(tr2);       

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.removeView()` method and as a parameter use the index of the table row you want to delete or add a unique tag to the table row and remove it based on this tag later.

Comment: can you please tell me how to retrieve clicked row index?

Comment: ok, i solved my problem..first problem was  tr = new TableRow(this); i couldn't assign id to my table row because id didn't instantiate it in my class

Answer (score 0):

set also id as a tag in every row. when deleting unique row then use .removeView(view.getTag());

Comment: for some reason, tags and ids won't work, i managed to delete row when i inputed in code row index, and now i don't know how to get index of clicked row

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0, j < table.getChildCount(); i < j; i++){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) getChildAt(i);
    if(you can check something here) {
        removeViewAt(i);
        // or...
        removeView(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, this looks promising, but i still don't get how to retrieve child row index

Comment: What way are you going to delete the row? By clicking for example?

Comment: yes, and i have alertdialog which pops up when i click row, and method for deleting it...